# How to sepearate the validation code from html page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I tried with ng-bind-html but im not getting how to seperate the validation codes from html page .i need to maintain the validation error file in seperate page

```
 div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>{{ 'EMPLOYEEID' | translate }} :</label>
          <input type="text" name="empId" class="form-control" ng-model="EmpId" placeholder="{{ 'EMPLOYEEID' | translate }}">
          <p ng-show="userForm.empId.$invalid && !userForm.empId.$pristine" class="help-block requiredText">{{'EMPLOYEE_ID_VALIDATE' | translate}}</p>

        </div>




        <div class="form-group">
          <label>{{ 'EMPLOYEE_NAME' | translate }} : <spn class="manadatoryIcon"> *</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="userName" class="form-control" ng-model="userName" placeholder="{{ 'EMPLOYEE_NAME' | translate }}" required>

       <div ng-messages="userForm.userName.$error">
        <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>{{ 'FATHER_HUSBAND_NAME' | translate }}:</label>
          <input type="text" name="fatherOrHusbandName" class="form-control" ng-model="fatherOrHusbandName" placeholder="{{ 'FATHER_HUSBAND_NAME' | translate }}">
          <p ng-show="userForm.fatherOrHusbandName.$invalid && !userForm.fatherOrHusbandName.$pristine" class="help-block requiredText">{{'FATHER_HUSBAND_NAME_VALID' | translate}}</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: SO, you want to put your validation code inside controller or inside a separate service file used by the controller

Comment: yeah anything is fine

Comment: please tell me if you know

Comment: Posted my answer, I have done the validation this way in my code as well.

Comment: can you please do in jsfiddle so i can understand better.below code not working in my application i tried.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want but i think you want to have a separated file with all messages.
You can use `ng-messages-include="messages.html"`
In this file you can define your "messages" with:

```
<ng-message when="required">{{ "ERROR_MSG_REQUIRED" | translate }}</ng-message>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Inside your controller create a function

    $scope.validateFormField = function(userForm, fieldType ) {
       var isValid = false;
       switch(fieldType ) {
          case 'fatherOrHusbandName' : isValid =userForm.fatherOrHusbandName.$invalid && !userForm.fatherOrHusbandName.$pristine;
     break;

          case 'name': isValid = userForm.empId.$invalid && !userForm.empId.$pristine
         break;

         default : isValid = {{Do it yourself}}
         break;

       }
       return isValid ;
    }
```

in your html

```
div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>{{ 'EMPLOYEEID' | translate }} :</label>
          <input type="text" name="empId" class="form-control" ng-model="EmpId" placeholder="{{ 'EMPLOYEEID' | translate }}">
          <p ng-show="validateFormField(userForm, 'name')" class="help-block requiredText">{{'EMPLOYEE_ID_VALIDATE' | translate}}</p>

        </div>




        <div class="form-group">
          <label>{{ 'EMPLOYEE_NAME' | translate }} : <spn class="manadatoryIcon"> *</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="userName" class="form-control" ng-model="userName" placeholder="{{ 'EMPLOYEE_NAME' | translate }}" required>

       <div ng-messages="userForm.userName.$error">
        <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>{{ 'FATHER_HUSBAND_NAME' | translate }}:</label>
          <input type="text" name="fatherOrHusbandName" class="form-control" ng-model="fatherOrHusbandName" placeholder="{{ 'FATHER_HUSBAND_NAME' | translate }}">
          <p ng-show="validateFormField(userForm, 'fatherOrHusbandName')"" class="help-block requiredText">{{'FATHER_HUSBAND_NAME_VALID' | translate}}</p>
        </div>
```